# Calculus - Extreme values unit - is this possible?

Tags: calculus

Explain if this is possible or not

$f'(x) > 0$ on $(-\infty, \infty)$

$f''(x) > 0$ on $(-\infty, 1)\cup(3,\infty)$ 
and
$f''(x) < 0$ on  $(1,3)$.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please don't just ask us to do your homework for you.

Comment: What are we supposed to do when a question is put on hold ? Should I delete my answer ?

Comment: No. Just leave it and hope someone gives you some points. I just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible and I'll give you a hint why this possible but you have to work out the details by yourself.

- The condition $f'(x) > 0$ on $(-\infty, \infty)$ means that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing.
- The condition $f''(x) > 0$ on $(-\infty,1) \cup (3, \infty)$ means that the function is convex  $(-\infty,1) \cup (3, \infty)$. (Google "convex function"; it roughly looks like a smile)
- The condition $f''(x) < 0$ on $(1,3)$ means that the function is concave on $(1,3)$. (it roughly looks like a frowny face)

Now $f(x) := e^x$ satisfy condition 1 and 2 (check it). Let's consider the function 
$$g(x) := \begin{cases}e^x ~~\text{on $(-\infty, 1)\cup (3, \infty)$} \\ \text{something else on $(1,3)$}\end{cases}$$

Can you find a concave function on $(1,3)$ whose value for $x = 1$ is $e$ and whose value for $x =3$ is $e^3$ ? Well I'm sure you drawn such function. Now try to find a formula for such a function.